# Crystal Report Designer: Retrieve query from broken SQL link

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

I have some problem with SAP Crystal Report. We have just upgraded the server, to the new server. Since the server did run in tandem with old server, we had to give it another name.

The problem, is that crystal report would not function at all to the new server. It saved the connection to old server at the .rpt file, and refuses to change the connection. All properties were grayed out, and cannot be changed to new connection.

So I made a new connection, and wanted to copy the SQL query to the new connection. But when I click on `View Command` or `Edit Command`, nothing happened.

Any idea on how to transfer existing .rpt file to the new server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating dummy server with name as old server. Doesn't need to have same table or anything, just dummy SQL server. The query suddenly works, albeit errors, but I can copy them all to new report